# Factory Girl - Make record and call function on it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

Whenever I make a User, I want to call build_user_group on that user. I use after_save:build_user_group on the User model to do this, but when FactoryGirl creates a user, build_user_group is never executed. How can I call it from inside the factory or make sure FactoryGirl doesn't skip the callback?

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to UserGroup
  after_save :build_user_group

  def build_user_group
    if self.user_group_id.present?
      self.user_group.update!(newest: self.name)
    else
      group = UserGroup.new(newest: self.name)
      group.user << self
      group.save!
    end
  end
end
```

-

```
# spec/factories.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name "Default Name"
    build_user_group #ArgumentError: Trait not registered: build_user_group
  end
end
```

I'm not calling build_user_group the right way. It thinks I'm trying to access a trait with that name. What's the correct way to call it?

Ideally, build_user_group would be a private function, but it can be public if that's easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a callback in FactoryGirl to call your method:

```
factory :product do
  name "Default Name"
  after(:build) do |p|
    p.build_user_group
  end
end
```

I presume the method isn't getting called when you build a product using your factory because your [FactoryGirl strategy](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#using-factories) is to `:build` rather than `:create` (although your question says 'create'). If it isn't calling that method when you are creating a product then there may be a deeper issue as to why your model callback isn't being invoked.

Answer (score 1):

You could mock it in your RSpec test like this:

```
  context "...." do
    it "...." do
      user_group = double("user_group")
      allow(user).to receive(:build_user_group).and_return(:user_group)
      expect(....).to eq(....)
    end
  end
```

See [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/method-stubs/allow-with-a-simple-return-value) for RSpec documentation with example.

Let me know if that works for you or if you have any other question!